# Trailing Comma in "settings.json" in VSCode 1.48

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code

I am a newbie in Vscode, I have started setting up the VScode editor for my Python learning. One thing that is bugging me is Trialing Comma Error in Problem. Could you please help me with this?
Thanks in advance.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSSoL.png)

Issue details
// Trims lines that contain only whitespace after pressing Enter on them.
"pythonIndent.trimLinesWithOnlyWhitespace": false,

// After creating a hanging indent, press tab to leave the indented section and go to the ending bracket.
"pythonIndent.useTabOnHangingIndent": false

}
,
]

Comment: why are you editing the Global default settings file? If your User setting or Workspace settings have 4k lines you have very much tailored VSC.

Comment: Thanks for the response rio,I have not tried any changes to the Global settings, but the error shows in the location referring to Global settings. I have tried clean uninstall (removed all extensions) and installed Vscode again, still issue persists.

Comment: Why is your settings.json file 4K lines? Only add the entries that are different from the default values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a `settings.json` file is a dictionary with keys. No array of dictionaries.

the simplest `settings.json` file with 3 keys

```
{
  "editor.tabSize": 2,
  "editor.detectIndentation": false,
  "workbench.activityBar.visible": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an actual issue: [Github Issues site](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/105414)

I am getting the same error.  Note as per comments his settings file is NOT 4k lines, this is the "combined" settings file created by VS Code.  My actual settings.json file (Win10 location: C:\Users<username>\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\settings.json) is 52 lines, but the file shown by Code with the error is about 3900 lines (Im guessing combined from various sources which I have yet to track down).  Will update when fix found - currently some back and forth in the thread (see link).